# Catching plugin issues in hapi 17

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm using hapi17 and building a simple plugin wrapper around `pg` (https://node-postgres.com for access to Postgresql).

I suspect I am making a simple Javascript-noob error here, but I can't quite figure where.

My plugin code looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const {Pool} = require('pg');

exports.plugin = {
    name: 'pgPlugin',
    version: '0.0.1',
    register: async function (server, options) {
        const pgUser=server.configue.get('postgresql.username');
        const pgPass=server.configue.get('postgresql.password');
        const pgHost=server.configue.get('postgresql.host');
        const pgPort=server.configue.get('postgresql.port');
        const pgDb=server.configue.get('postgresql.database');
        const pool = new Pool ({
            user: pgUser,
            password:pgPass,
            database:pgDb,
            host:pgHost,
            port:pgPort
        });
        console.log('Postgresql setup complete');
        pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
            console.error('Unexpected error on idle client', err);
        });
       server.decorate('toolkit','doPostgresQuery',async (query,params) => {
            try {
                const {rows} = await pool.query(query,params);
                return rows;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('here');
                console.log(e.stack);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

At the moment, for example, I have bad credentials set in my config, so as expected `pg` fails and logs the following to the console :

```
here
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED database.server:5342
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
```

However, my code just flows straight through to "ok", `Boom.badRequest` never getst called :

```
const rows = h.doPostgresQuery('select foobar from foo where bar =$1',[123]);
console.log(rows);
if (!rows) {
    return Boom.badRequest('error');
}
return 'OK';
```

I have tried re-writing to `const rows = await h.doPostgresQuery(...` but this yields an errror:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Which is strange because `server.decorate` defines an async function ?

**UPDATE**

Extra code for clarification:

The Route:

```
exports.plugin = {
    name: 'blahPlugin',
    version: '0.0.1',
    register: async function (server, options) {
        server.route({
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/test',
            handler: blahController.test,
            options: {
                validate: {
                    payload: blahValidator.smsValidator,
                    failAction: handleValidationError.errorHandler
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

The controller:

```
exports.test = (request, h) => {
    const rows = await h.doPostgresQuery('select foobar from foo where bar = $1',[123]);
    console.log(rows);
    if (!rows) {
        return Boom.badRequest('error');
    }
    return 'OK';

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your doPostgresQuery is returning a promise, but you are not waiting for a response.

There is an error because you need to declare your handler as an async function, then you can use await in your queries, or you need to use `h.doPostgresQuery.then((rows))` notation.

Here is a sample:

```
exports.myHandler = {
    description: 'get something',    
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        try {

            const rows = await h.doPostgresQuery('select foobar from foo where bar =$1',[123]);

            if (!rows) {
                return Boom.badRequest('error');
            }

            return rows

        } catch (e) {
            return Boom.badRequest(e.message, e);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am a little confused, am I already not awaiting a response in my controller code (see updated question above) ?

Comment: you need to define your controller as async, try this: `exports.test = async (request, h) => {}`, then it should work with `await` operator.